# Weighted Absolute Error implementation doesn't work in tensorflow (keras)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have created custom loss (Weighted Absolute error) in keras but implementation doesn't work - I get an error `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['my_model/conv2d/kernel:0', 'my_model/conv2d/bias:0'].`
I want to apply different weight for each pixel.

```
class WeightedMeanAbsoluteError(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):

    def __init__(self, name='weighted_mean_absolute_error'):
        super(WeightedMeanAbsoluteError, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.wmae = self.add_weight(name='wmae', initializer='zeros')

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, loss_weights):
        values = tf.math.abs(y_true - y_pred) * loss_weights
        return self.wmae.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

    def result(self):
        return self.wmae

    def reset_states(self):
        # The state of the metric will be reset at the start of each epoch.
        self.wmae.assign(0.)
loss_object = WeightedMeanAbsoluteError()
train_loss = WeightedMeanAbsoluteError()
```

I use the following code to implement a training step:

```
@tf.function
def train_step(input_images, output_images):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        # training=True is only needed if there are layers with different
        # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
        result_images = model(input_images, training=True)
        loss = loss_object(output_images, result_images)
    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

Also my code works just fine if I use

```
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()
train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best and simple way to minimize a weighted standard loss (such mae) is using the sample_weights parameter in fit method where we pass an array with the desired weight of each sample

```
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (1000,50))
y = np.random.uniform(0,1, 1000)
W = np.random.randint(1,10, 1000)

inp = Input((50))
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(inp)
out = Dense(10)(x)
model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile('adam','mae')

model.fit(X,y, epochs=100, sample_weights=W)
```